# malloc/free() with error signal 6

Tags: c, memory, malloc, heap-memory, free

Here is a basic stack implementation code. However, it generates signal abort.

```
int *arr;
int size = 2;
int top = 0;

int pop() {

    int i;
    if (top <= size / 4) {
        int *arr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size / 2);
        for ( i = 0; i < size; i++)
            arr2[i] = arr[i];
        free(arr);
        arr = arr2;
        size /= 2;
    }
    return arr[--top];
}

void push( int a) {

    int i;
    if (top >= size) {
        int *arr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size * 2);
        for ( i = 0; i < size; i++)
            arr2[i] = arr[i];
        free(arr);
        arr = arr2;
        size *= 2;
    }   
    arr[top++] = a;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
*** glibc detected *** a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0804a030 ***
```

and the debug data shows aborted sig 6 The interesting thing is  that it shows the line of free() but As 4386427 said, the problem is accessing out of bounds of memory while copying arr2 of size

[image]

> ## 0  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
>
> ## 1  0xb7e8a7d0 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
>
> ## 2  0xb7e8bea3 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
>
> ## 3  0xb7ebff8b in __libc_message () from /lib/libc.so.6
>
> ## 4  0xb7ec5911 in malloc_printerr () from /lib/libc.so.6
>
> ## 5  0xb7ec6f84 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
>
> ## 6  0x080484a0 in pop () at stacks_eng.c:14
>
> ## 7  0x0804867e in main () at stacks_eng.c:55 (gdb) f 6
>
> ## 6  0x080484a0 in pop () at stacks_eng.c:14 14                      free(arr);

Comment: How and where is `arr` initialized?

Comment: On what inputs does the program crash? Provide a [MCVE]

Comment: You return arr , which is already free'd.

Comment: OT: You should consider putting `arr`, `top`, `size` into a struct and pass that struct to the `push`/`pop` functions. Global variables are bad....

Comment: On a side-note, [don't cast malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: Tim Čas why are you offering not to cast. It is necessary not to get a warning from GCC, isn't it? Moreover, it provides parsing 4 bytes  between arr[i] and arr[i+1]

Comment: Tsakiroglou Fotis, no I've already assigned a different address of the memory in which arr2 stores into variable arr, so it's not a freed address anymore.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be more issues but here is a starter:

```
int *arr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size / 2);
```

This makes the size of `arr2` be **half** of `size` and then you do:

```
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr2[i] = arr[i];
```

So you are clearly writing out of bounds, i.e. undefined behavior.

Maybe you wanted:

```
size /= 2;
```

**before** the loop.

BTW: Check the `realloc` function. It seems to be what you need. It will perform better and you wont have to write the code to copy elements yourself.

Comment: Many thanks. It worked clearly. The reason that I missed the point is that I focused more on free () function where gdb points. And Since it could be a bit complicated, I couldn't analyze Valgrind's feedback. I wish I would have listened to him.

Comment: Yes, definitely look into `realloc`.  It will save you from having to copy the array every time as it will be able to simply shrink its footprint when resizing to be smaller, and when growing, will grow in place if possible.  `realloc` aside, you can use `memcpy` to copy a contiguous set of memory.